# ¿como puedo traer el contenido de una celda de otro libro en base al valor de una celda del libro actual?

Tags: excel, formulas, microsoft-office

Tengo una libro llamado lazo con este contenido, y creé una lista desplegable con los datos de la fila A del libro lazo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que en la columna C del libro personas, por ejemplo la columna C1 me traiga el valor del libro lazo de la columna B1 que coincida con el valor seleccionado de la lista desplegabla del libro personas con la columna A del libro lazo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Estoy usando Excel 2007*

Tengo una fórmula con la función INDIRECTO pero no me atrevo a ponerla porque puede generar ruido en vez de información.

¿Alguna idea que me pueda ayudar?

**ACTUALIZACION**

Donde digo *libro* quise decir *hoja*, no modifico la pregunta para que se entienda la estructura de la respuesta del amigo Hubert Ronald

Comment: ¿Por qué en 2 libros diferentes? Aun así, un BUSCARV debería funcionarte.

Comment: porque eventualmente se va a mandar a hacer unas encuestas y no queremos que las personas pongan un resultado a los parámetros que que queremos y después ese listado será un insumo para una base de datos y es mucho mas cómodo trabajar con numero que con caracteres,  ¿nos puedes ayduar con un ejemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si son dos archivos diferentes (libros) se tiene la situación que señalas, porque un archivo es enviado y el otro no.

> La recomendación es que trabajes un sólo archivo (libro) y en hojas separadas (personas y lazo) siendo en este caso la `hoja lazo` la que se puede proteger de las usuarios mediante tres pasos: poner blanco el texto de todas las celdas, bloquear la hoja con una contraseña y ocultarla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este [post](https://exceltotal.com/listas-desplegables-dependientes-en-excel/) también encontrarás más detalle sobre listas desplegables usando `INDIRECTO`, pero no se menciona cómo indexar las listas en cuestión.

Es posible como bien han indicado arriba emplear la función `BUSCARV`, pero es importante acotar que los datos del tipo texto deben estar ordenados alfabéticamente, aquí comparto un [post](https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/3416-como-ordenar-y-buscar-datos-vlookup-excel-2016/) sobre el particular.

> El tema está cuando queremos personalizar nuestras listas desplegables en un orden especifico por ejemplo `Principiante, Fácil, Intermedio, Difícil, Avanzado`

Para ello, existe una función `SUMAR.SI`, en tal sentido, se requiere dar un nombre a la lista y sus indices -en este caso para que el usuario no sepa qué provienen de la `hoja lazo`-.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en la celda `C1` de la hoja `personas` puedes usar la siguiente expresión

```
=SI(ESBLANCO(B1);"";SUMAR.SI(desple;B1;idDeple))
```

donde:

```
desple = lazo!$A$1:$A$6
idDeple = lazo!$B$1:$B$6
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]