# BUSCARV Excel 2010

Tags: excel, filtro, indices

Tengo un archivo `excel` con dos hojas `export` y `consolidado`, quiero traer `3` datos de la hoja `consolidado` y ubicarla en los campo de la hoja `export`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He mirado varias fórmulas de `BUSCARV` pero me salen `0` u otros caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

1. En la hoja `consolidado` deberías tener la columna `NUMERO_ID` antes `TIPO_ID`. Es decir, intercambiar las columnas `G` y `H` ya que la búsqueda se realiza por la primera columna de la matriz de búsqueda
2. En la hoja `export` **no debes** insertar el número de documento entre comillas simples ya que la fórmula `BUSCARV`, busca un documento **exactamente igual** en la matriz de búsqueda
3. En la hoja `export` las fórmulas deben quedar de la siguiente manera:

*celda F2* `=BUSCARV(G2;consolidado!G:O;2;0)`

*celda I2* `=BUSCARV(G2;consolidado!G:O;7;0)`

*celda J2* `=BUSCARV(G2;consolidado!G:O;9;0)`

Con esto debería funcionar!!!

Answer (score 0):

## Consideraciones

Cuando se trabaja con `BUSCARV` hay que tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

> 1. La columna que servirá de referencia para el indexado, tiene que estar en orden ascendente (ya sea número o alfabéticamente): comenté más sobre esto en este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/241097/como-puedo-traer-el-contenido-de-una-celda-de-otro-libro-en-base-al-valor-de-un)
> 2. Se debe verificar que la precitada columna no contenga elementos (indices) repetidos.
> 3. La columna de indexado tiene que estar necesariamente en la primera columna a la izquierda, en el caso de la columna que se empleará como consulta, no es obligatorio hacer lo anterior, pero es una buena practica que se coloque también a la izquierda.

Para esta respuesta se ha trabajado todas las columnas con los indices en la columna: `A` tanto de la hoja **export** como de la hoja **consolidado**

En la hoja: **consolidado** la columna no está ordenada ascendentemente, pero `NUMERO_ID` no contiene elementos repetidos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto al emplear `BUSCARV` en la hoja: **export**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No coinciden los datos

> Pero en este caso sí es válido que en la columna `A` de la Hoja **export** existan indices repetidos.

## Solución

En la hoja **consolidado** como ya se verificó que no hay indices repetidos en la columna **A** se le aplica filtro: `Ascendente`, luego es opcional, pero para mantener un orden, seleccionar el rango en este caso de `$A$1:$O$14` y [asignarle el nombre](https://www.gerencie.com/definir-nombres-de-rango-en-excel.html) de `tbConsolidado`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la hoja **export** por tanto, se tiene las consultas correctas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una de las ventajas de trabajar a partir de la **columna A** cuando se tienen muchas columnas es tomar ventaja de la función `COLUMNA` esta devolverá un indice si `A es 1`, si `B es 2`, si `C es 3`,... y dado que la función `BUSCARV` necesita que se le indique la posición de la columna, se automatiza este procedimiento.

Por tanto estas son las expresiones que va en este caso en la celda `F2`, `I2` y `J2` de la hoja **export** respectivamente:

```
=BUSCARV($A2; tbConsolidado; COLUMNA(consolidado!G$1))
=BUSCARV($A2; tbConsolidado; COLUMNA(consolidado!M$1))
=BUSCARV($A2; tbConsolidado; COLUMNA(consolidado!O$1))
```

A continuación el detalle de una de las expresiones, que puede ser extrapolada a las demás:

```
=BUSCARV(
          $A2;                     -- valor a buscar, el carácter '$' al inicio,
                                   -- fijará la columna A, más no las filas

          tbConsolidado;           -- tabla que corresponde al rango $A$1:$O$14 

          COLUMNA(consolidado!G$1) -- devuelve 7 que es el número de la columna G 
                                   -- esto funciona porque tbConsolidado empieza en A
                                   -- el carácter '$' entre G y 1, permite arrastrar 
                                   -- a la derecha o a la izquierda la fórmula y capturar
                                   -- el número de columna correspondiente a tbConsolidado
                                   -- es decir se fija en este caso a la fila 1
                                   -- pero las columnas varian
         )
```